# Using unsigned in C with negative temporary results

Tags: c, unsigned, integer-arithmetic

From what I understand, in C the `unsigned` type behaves like arithmetic (assuming `unsigned` has 32-bit length) in the integer ring modulo 4294967296.

So, it seems to follow from basic ring theory, that if we have an integer (now I mean ℤ !) calculation involving `*` `+` `-`, then no matter what kind of overflows and underflows temporarily happen, the end result *will* be correct, as long as the end result is in the range [0, 2^32] ?

For example, in the following calculation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  unsigned v = 50000;
  unsigned w = 100000;
  unsigned x = 300000;
  unsigned y = 20000;
  unsigned z = 4000000000;

  unsigned r = v*w - x*y + z;

  printf("v*w - x*y + z = %u \n", r);

  return 0;
}
```

we have temporary results that differ from the results which we would get if we would calculate in ℤ, but we still get the right answer.

Is this right or can anything go wrong?

Comment: This is correct. There are no negative temporary results, all the steps are done using modular arithmetic.

Comment: As a personal note: `4*1000*1000*1000` is bit more typing, but much more readable (and I doubt you will type this very often). Too bad C does not allow underscores in integer constants.

Comment: Or `# define BILLION * 1000 * 1000 * 1000` followed by `unsigned z = 4 BILLION;` - I've often found that more readable. At least until we get user defined literals a la C++, or Perl's nifty `1_000_000`-type literals.

Comment: @paxdiablo or `4 THOUSAND MILLION` for the British coders

Comment: note: this works for `unsigned int`, and larger unsigned integer types - not necessarily for `unsigned short` and `unsigned char` because of integer promotion.

Comment: @M.M: well that would be `MILLIARD` but the vast majority of Brits I know (in fact, most non-US bods) seem to use the US scale nowadays. But we'll be long dead in the ground before we revert back to the quaint gallons, quarts and so on :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Is not `4*1000*1000*1000` --> UB (`int` overflow)?  Certainly it is an `int`.  Or is it all done with `intmax_t`?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Problem is `BILLION` is confusing for e.g. Germans, who interpret this as `1000*1000*1000*1000`. As numbers are more problematic to translate in mind than text, it is an potential source of errors. Hmm, I didn't even know there is a "MILLIARD" in English, too! Fascinating ...

Comment: @chux: Good point (to all of us). It should be `4U* ...`. Actually better `UINT32_C(4)*...`.

Comment: I'd suggest `4LU` to address those pesky 16-bit `unsigned` or `UINT32_C(4) ...` as you comment,

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `C11 6.2.5 Types /9` (my emphasis):

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because *a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.*

In other words, provided the types are unsigned, and the modulus value you want to use is `UINT_MAX + 1`, and the type is the right width (all these are true is in this particular case), this will work as expected.

You should, however, be properly specifying the constants as unsigned so as to ensure there's no issue with overflow in the constant itself (C will use a wider signed type in that case so, assuming you can assign that wider type to an `unsigned int`, there should be no issues - there may be issues if, for example, you're not using a two's complement implementation, unlikely though that is).

You should also use a type *guaranteed* to be big enough since `unsigned int` may, on some platforms, be less than 32 bits wide.

In other words, your statements should be of the form:

```
unsigned long z = 4000000000U;
```

That, of course, means you may need to do your *own* modulus operations since an `unsigned long` may be *more* than 32 bits wide.

Of course, if your platform provides them, it's *far* more preferable to use the fixed-width types, `uint32_t` in your case. That way, you get a Goldilocks type (neither too small nor too big, and definitely two's complement)) and you can let C itself handle the modulo operations:

```
uint32_t z = 4000000000U;
```

*That* is the solution I'd be going for.

Comment: The quoted standard paragraph is irrelevant; it is saying that the thing the standard calls "overflow", which is undefined behaviour, does not happen for unsigned operands because it is defined not to. Instead, something else happens that most people still call "overflow" but the standard doesn't.

Comment: @immibis, I perhaps wasn't clear there,the snippet specifically states the behaviour of moving beyond the ends of the range. I included the entire paragraph but the important bit is not "can never overflow" as you suggest, but "is reduced modulo ...". I'll highlight that to make it clearer. For what it's worth (which may not be much), what "most" [citation needed :-) ] people call overflow, I call wraparound.

Comment: What do you mean by: *Technically, 4000000000 is an signed constant and will likely overflow your 32-bit signed integer type.* ? OP is assigning to unsigned types which cannot overflow.

Comment: @2501, the constant itself has a data type. It's no different to `int x = 2.5;` which assigns the `double` constant to an integer. You can run into real trouble by assuming an expression will use the type of what it will eventually be assigned to, such as `double will_be_zero = 1 / 5;`.

Comment: I've adjusted the language to try and make it clearer. In actuality it, won't overflow the 32-bit signed type, C will instead use a larger type, one that can fit the value.

Comment: That is what I was hinting at, the value will be represented in a larger type. The assignment to unsigned will only wrap.

Comment: So it works for `*`, `+` and `-`. This question is more mathematical. Because it may be easy to see that it works, but it is not *obvious.* For example, it does not work with `/`. The exact mathematical result of `3*(4717296 + 65500*65500)/2 -6442450940` is `4`, so well in the range of 32-bit unsigneds. But calculating this with 32-bit unsigneds will give a wrong result.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats, yes. If you need to divide then you can run into trouble. The basic rule is that *every* operation may be subject to a modulus operation, not just the final result. If your primary concern is ensuring accuracy, your best bet is to choose a large enough data type to handle all intermediate values. Even if C doesn't provide something big enough, there are plenty of arbitrary precision libraries (such as MPIR).